# aws python boto: looking for reliable way to interrupt get_contents_to_filename

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, interrupt

I have a python function that downloads a file from S3 to some temp location on a local drive and then processes it. The download part looks like this:

```
 def processNewDataFile(key):

     ## templocation below is just some temp local path
     key.get_contents_to_filename(templocation)
     ## further processing
```

Here `key` is the AWS key for the file to download. What I've noticed is that occasionally `get_contents_to_filename` seems to freeze. In other parts of my code I have some solution that interrupts blocks of code (and raises an exception) if these blocks do not complete in a specified amount of time. This solution is hard to use here since files that I need to download vary in size a lot and sometimes S3 responds slower than other times.

So is there any reliable way of interrupting/timing out `get_contents_to_filename` that does NOT involve a hard predetermined time limit?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a callback function with `get_contents_to_filename`

http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/gs.html#boto.gs.key.Key.get_contents_to_file

The callback function needs two parameters, Bytes Sent and Total Size of the file.
You can specify the granularity (maximum number of times the callback will get called) as well although I've only used it with small files (less than 10kb) and it usually only gets called twice - once on start and once on end.

The important thing is that it will pass the size of the file to the callback function at the start of the transfer, which could then start a timer based on the size of the file.